Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/polyfill'
I'm using webpack with babel, vanillaJS for web clone project. when I trying to run the webpack
 ("dev:assets": "cross-env WEBPACK_ENV=development webpack -w")

, then this error comes out.
ERROR in multi @babel/polyfill ./assets/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/polyfill' in 'C:\Users\82106\wetube'      
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./assets/js/main.js main[0]
someone recommende

d me to install 'core-js', but error still exist.
here's my github.

webpack.config.js
https://github.com/miri9/wetube/blob/master/webpack.config.js

package config json file
https://github.com/miri9/wetube/blob/master/package.json



I had the same problem. I added this "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1", to my dev dependencies in package.json and ran npm install. That resolved the issue.
